# Unable to use http connector

Tags: camunda

I'm trying to use the http connector that is provided with the standard Camunda implementation with no luck. Every single time that I run my workflow the instance simply freeze on that activity. I'm using this class in an execution listnener and the code that I'm using is this:

```
import org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.Expression;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.json.JSONObject;
import org.camunda.connect.Connectors;
import org.camunda.connect.ConnectorException;
import org.camunda.connect.httpclient.HttpConnector;
import org.camunda.connect.httpclient.HttpResponse;
import org.camunda.connect.httpclient.impl.HttpConnectorImpl;
import org.camunda.connect.impl.DebugRequestInterceptor;



public class APIAudit implements JavaDelegate {
static {
    LogFactory.useSlf4jLogging(); // MyBatis
  }

private static final java.util.logging.Logger LOGGER = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName());

private Expression tokenField;
private Expression apiServerField;
private Expression questionIDField;
private Expression subjectField;
private Expression bodyField;

public void execute(DelegateExecution arg0) throws Exception {

    String tokenValue = (String) tokenField.getValue(arg0);
    String apiServerValue = (String) apiServerField.getValue(arg0);
    String questionIDValue = (String) questionIDField.getValue(arg0);
    String subjectValue = (String) subjectField.getValue(arg0);
    String bodyValue = (String) bodyField.getValue(arg0);
    if (apiServerValue != null) {
        String url = "http://" + apiServerValue + "/v1.0/announcement";

        LOGGER.info("token: " + tokenValue);
        LOGGER.info("apiServer: " + apiServerValue);
        LOGGER.info("questionID: " + questionIDValue);
        LOGGER.info("subject: " + subjectValue);
        LOGGER.info("body: " + bodyValue);
        LOGGER.info("url: " + url);

        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("access_token", tokenValue);
        jsonBody.put("source", "SYSTEM");
        jsonBody.put("target", "AUDIT");
        jsonBody.put("tType", "system");
        jsonBody.put("aType", "auditLog");
        jsonBody.put("affectedItem", questionIDValue);
        jsonBody.put("subject", subjectValue);
        jsonBody.put("body", bodyValue);
        jsonBody.put("language", "EN");

        try {
            LOGGER.info("Generating connection");

            HttpConnector http = Connectors.getConnector(HttpConnector.ID);

            LOGGER.info(http.toString());
            DebugRequestInterceptor interceptor = new DebugRequestInterceptor(false);
            http.addRequestInterceptor(interceptor);

            LOGGER.info("JSON Body: " + jsonBody.toString());

            HttpResponse response = http.createRequest()
                                        .post()
                                        .url(url)
                                        .contentType("application/json")
                                        .payload(jsonBody.toString())
                                        .execute();

            Integer responseCode = response.getStatusCode();
            String responseBody = response.getResponse();
            response.close();
            LOGGER.info("[" + responseCode + "]: " + responseBody);
        } catch (ConnectorException e) {
            LOGGER.severe(e.getMessage());
        }


    } else {

        LOGGER.info("No APISERVER provided");

    }

    LOGGER.info("Exiting");

}
}
```

I'm sure that the fields injection works correctly since the class prints the correct values. I also used the http-connector in javascript in the same activity with no problem.

I'm using this approach since I need to make two different calls to external REST services in the same task, so any advice will be very welcome.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?. I have a similar problem where I use a JavaDelegate to perform HTTP requests. The response is returned as null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Connect process engine plugin in process engine configuration. Not sure how you configured the process engine, make sure to add this plugin org.camunda.connect.plugin.impl.ConnectProcessEnginePlugin

Also check the following in dependencies

1. Do not add both dependencies - connectors-all and http-connector.
2. Make sure to check the error logs and see whether you have any class loading problem related to httpclient classes

I am pretty sure there is a class loading issue with http client library. make sure to include the correct version of connectors-all dependency